# Git log search igoring changes?

Tags: git

I wrote

```
git log -SMyTextStringHere --source --all
```

I expect git to search the the text MyTextStringHere in source code of all branches. I get ONE result. When I introduce it last week. What I expected to get was my latest change which was `string MyTextStringHere;` to `string MyTextStringHere=""`. This change was today, I can see it in my source code and I can see it on github.

Why doesn't git log search show me this change? It works on a line bases and that line is affected so I expect to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `git log -S` state:

> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>. Note that this is
>   different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in
>   gitdiffcore(7) for more details.

The referenced section of the `gitdiffcore` man page states in part:

> When diffcore-pickaxe is in use, it checks if there are filepairs whose "result" side and whose
>   "origin" side have different number of specified string.

The number of occurrences of your search string wouldn't increase or decrease as a result of the change that you were expecting to find, thus that commit should not be found.

Using the `-G` option rather than `-S` should give you the results that you were expecting.